# Add a Print Button to Vendor Credits (view mode) with Advanced PDF Template in Netsuite SuiteScripts 2.0

Tags: pdf, netsuite, suitescript

Since I myself had some problems creating a print button, I'd like to make my scripts available here for creating a print button. I hope it will help one or the other :-)

You only need to integrate three scripts and change the ID in the respective scripts.

Suitelet script (vc_print_button_suitelet.js):

```
    define(['N/render', 'N/record', 'N/xml'], function(render, record, xml) 
   {

  function onRequest(context) {

    var custom_id = context.request.parameters.custom_id;
    var pdfFileName = "vendorcredit";
    var renderer = render.create();
    var content = renderer.addRecord({
      templateName: 'record',
      record: record.load({
        type: record.Type.VENDOR_CREDIT,
        id: custom_id
      })
    });
    renderer.setTemplateByScriptId("CUSTTMPL_112_5298640_SB1_621");
    context.response.setHeader({
      name: 'content-disposition',
      value: 'inline; filename="' + pdfFileName + '_' + custom_id + '.pdf"'
    });
    context.response.writeFile(renderer.renderAsPdf());
  }
  return {
    onRequest: onRequest
  }
  })
```

Client script (vc_print_button_client.js):

```
define(['N/url', 'N/currentRecord'], function(url, currentRecord) {

  var exports = {};

  function pageInit(context) {
    // TODO
  }

  function onButtonClick() {
    var suiteletUrl = url.resolveScript({
      scriptId: 'customscript_vc_print_button_suitelet',
      deploymentId: 'customdeploy_vc_print_button_suitelet',
      returnExternalUrl: false,
      params: {
        custom_id: currentRecord.get().id,
      },
    });

    window.open(suiteletUrl);
  }

  exports.onButtonClick = onButtonClick;
  exports.pageInit = pageInit;
  return exports;
});
```

Event script (vc_print_button_event.js):

```
define([], function() {

  var exports = {};

  function beforeLoad(context) {
    context.form.addButton({
      id: "custpage_vcpb",
      label: "Print",
      functionName: "onButtonClick"
    });
    context.form.clientScriptModulePath = "SuiteScripts/vcPrintButton/vc_print_button_client.js";
  }

  exports.beforeLoad = beforeLoad;
  return exports;
});
```

Comment: Like @bknights said, please add in your question part of your template code : the part where you are trying to display your record data (example: <td align="center">${record.otherrefnum}</td> )

Comment: The question was edited, but you didn't add what we asked for : part of the PDF Template code (part from CUSTTMPL_112_5298640_SB1_621 )!

Answer (score 2):

1. displaying the PDF in the browser depends on a couple of things. One is how your browser is set up to handle PDFs and you can't do anything about that. The other is making sure you set a content disposition header:

   `response.setHeader({name:'content-disposition', value: 'inline; filename="'+ pdfFileName +'"'});`
2. Your PDF is being generated but is not getting values from the record. Based on the code supplied your template should reference fields like `${vendorcredit.tranid}` and `<#list vendorcredit.apply as item>...</#list>` If it is doing that properly then you might want to add your template code to the question.