# Netsuite Custom Print Button to HTML Template

Tags: pdf, netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm trying to get a print button to appear when in view mode on a Vendor return authorisation or VRMA that will print a custom HTML template to be used for labelling.

the below scripts are in place. everything looks to be working apart from when the button is clicked I'm getting no template appear.

the only error i get is when i try and execute the suitelet from within the script deployment

org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "customid" is not defined. (/SuiteScripts/vrma_print_button_suitelet.js#17)

Client Script
name: Vrma_print_button
id: customscript3535

```
`/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType ClientScript
 * Version    Date            Author            Remarks
 * 1.00       27/02/2023      Rayne     Initial Development
 *
 * 
 */
`define(['N/url', 'N/currentRecord'], function(url, currentRecord) {

  var exports = {};

  function pageInit(context) {
    // TODO
  }

  function onButtonClick() {
    var suiteletUrl = url.resolveScript({
      scriptId: 'customscriptvrma_print_button_suitelet',
      deploymentId: 'customdeployvrma_print_button_suitelet',
      returnExternalUrl: false,
      params: {
        custom_id: currentRecord.get().id,
      },
    });

    window.open(suiteletUrl);
  }

  exports.onButtonClick = onButtonClick;
  exports.pageInit = pageInit;
  return exports;
});
``
```

NAME
vrma_print_button_suitelet
ID
customscript3536

```
`/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType Suitelet
 * Version    Date            Author            Remarks
 * 1.00       27/02/2023      Rayne     Initial Development
 *
 * 
` */
    define(['N/render', 'N/record', 'N/xml'], function(render, record, xml) 
   {

  function onRequest(context) {

    var custom_id = context.request.parameters.custom_id;
    var pdfFileName = "VRMA Sticker";
    var renderer = render.create();
    var content = renderer.addRecord({
      templateName: 'record',
      record: record.load({
        type: record.Type.VENDOR_RETURN_AUTHORIZATION,
        id: custom_id
      })
    });
    renderer.setTemplateByScriptId("CUSTTMPL_113_5681957_SB1_699");
    context.response.setHeader({
      name: 'content-disposition',
      value: 'inline; filename="' + pdfFileName + '_' + custom_id + '.pdf"'
    });
    context.response.writeFile(renderer.renderAsPdf());
  }
  return {
    onRequest: onRequest
  }
  })
```

Button Appears correctly,
I'm getting no error messages that i can see, and its pointing at the relevant HTML template ID:

but when clicking the custom Print Button, i'm not getting any results.

where am i going wrong in the above 3 scripts.
this is my first time at scripts so i'm brand new to the above.
I've adapted alot of the code to suite our needs from the below poster.

[Add a Print Button to Vendor Credits (view mode) with Advanced PDF Template in Netsuite SuiteScripts 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56165306/add-a-print-button-to-vendor-credits-view-mode-with-advanced-pdf-template-in-n)

setup client, suitelet and user event script, custom html template.

expected upon click of the button the print template to appear.

**latest error** 3/4/23 following update to Suitelet.
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"load: Missing a required argument: id","stack":["createError(N/error)","onRequest(/SuiteScripts/vrma_print_button_suitelet.js:17)","createError(N/error)"],"cause":{"name":"SSS_MISSING_REQD_ARGUMENT","message":"load: Missing a required argument: id"},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":true}

user Event

```
define([], function() {

  var exports = {};

  function beforeLoad(context) {
    context.form.addButton({
      id: "custpage_vcpb",
      label: "Print",
      functionName: "onButtonClick"
    });
    context.form.clientScriptModulePath = "SuiteScripts/vrma_print_button_client.js";
  }

  exports.beforeLoad = beforeLoad;
  return exports;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line in your suitelet:

var custom_id = context.request.parameters.**customid**;

This should be:
var custom_id = context.request.parameters.**custom_id**;

Reason why is due to how you named the parameter in your client script:

```
params: {
    **custom_id**: currentRecord.get().id,
}
```

You will need to update the below accordingly also:

```
record: record.load({
    type: record.Type.VENDOR_RETURN_AUTHORIZATION,
    id: **custom_id**
  })
```

Comment: Hi @Arif Wb, I've updated the Suitelet as suggested.

I'm unsure where to go in regards to the updating the below. 

        type: record.Type.VENDOR_RETURN_AUTHORIZATION,
        id: custom_id

was there any additional changes regarding the client script? or was simply to advise why the error was happening.

looking at the rest of the script would you expect this to load a html template within the browser? 

i've included my latest error when try the URL from script deployment.

ive updated the scripts accordingly in the main post.

Comment: @Rayne - Your latest error indicates that you are missing an ID. It is likely the "custom_id" is not returning an ID from the client script. When you click the button and the Suitelet loads, can you check the URL and confirm that a value actually exists for the "&custom_id=" parameter? Better still, add log.debug('custom_id', custom_id) and check the script logs.

Comment: Hi @Arif WB

-sb1.app.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl?script=3536&deploy=1

i'm going to say its not picking up that value from the above.

regarding adding the log.debug('custom_id', custom_id)

would this be added to the suitelet or client side?  I've noticed I've not included the User Event script. I've added this to the top.

Comment: If custom_id does not exist on the Suitelet, there is no point debugging anything from there. On the client script, use the console to debug. Add console.log('id', currentRecord.get().id). Check that it returns a value before proceeding to debug the suitelet.

Comment: On the Client Side i've added the console.log notes that you advised.


  function onButtonClick() {
    var suiteletUrl = url.resolveScript({
      scriptId: 'customscriptvrma_print_button_suitelet',
      deploymentId: 'customdeployvrma_print_button_suitelet',
      returnExternalUrl: false,
      params: {
        console.log('id', currentRecord.get().id).
        custom_id: currentRecord.get().id,
      },
    });



However this now  Prompts  --Syntax error: missing : after property id--

on save, where am i going wrong at this stage, out of my depth at this point

Comment: No - you don't add the console.log line within the params. Add them at the start of the function.

Comment: Hi Arif, this isnt something i'm familiar with, are you able to send a screen grab on how this should sit ? 

i've tried adding this into a few different areas but kicks back an multiple different errors